# How can i solve the TypeError in Open Api Swagger?

Tags: javascript, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-editor

I am new in javascript and I try to write an open API swagger in YAML format. 
I use the online editor (https://editor.swagger.io). When I execute a call from this editor, I take the error:

> *TypeError: Failed to fetch*.

The produced cURL is correct because when I paste it to the postman, it works. What's wrong?

Comment: What's the full error message in the browser console?

Comment: Access to fetch at 'http://localhost...' from origin 'https://editor.swagger.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
localhost:... Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
swagger-ui.js:1 TypeError: Failed to fetch

I take this message.

Comment: Try with 127.0.0.1 instead

Comment: It still not working.

Comment: It's a CORS issue. You need to enable CORS on your server that's running on `localhost` . https://enable-cors.org/server.html